# How can I persists cookies across app restarts with WKWebView / WKHTTPCookieStore

Tags: swift, cookies, wkwebview, wkhttpcookiestore

I have a requirement to persist my cookies across application restarts.

Originally when using `UIWebView` I was able to achieve this with an extension on `UserDefaults`

```
import Foundation

extension UserDefaults {
    typealias CookieProperties = [HTTPCookiePropertyKey: Any]

    private static let cookieKey = "app_cookie_jar"

    func storeCookies() {
        guard let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies else { return }
        let cookiePropertiesArray = cookies.compactMap { $0.properties }
        set(cookiePropertiesArray, forKey: UserDefaults.cookieKey)
        synchronize()
    }

    func fetchCookies() {
        let cookiePropertiesArray = value(forKey: UserDefaults.cookieKey) as? [CookieProperties]
        cookiePropertiesArray?.forEach {
            if let cookie = HTTPCookie(properties: $0) {
                HTTPCookieStorage.shared.setCookie(cookie)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would then call this in various life cycle methods

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground() {
    defaults.fetchCookies()
    ...    
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground() {
    defaults.storeCookies()
    ...    
}
```

However now my application is using `WKWebView` and I have the same requirement. I am currently sharing the cookie store between the different web views in my app by way of a shared singleton `WKProcessPool`

```
class ProcessPool {
    static let shared = WKProcessPool()
}
```

However on a restart, some cookies are not persisted. Mainly cookies that do not have an `exp` date and cannot be updated on the server to have one.

The extension above is using `HTTPCookieStorage` however I need to achieve something of the same fashion (or better) using `WKHTTPCookieStore` and am unsure how.

I was hoping to do something like this

```
func storeCookies() {

    let __cookies = WKHTTPCookieStore()

    __cookies.getAllCookies { cookies in
        ....
    }
}
```

But I do not believe `WKHTTPCookieStore` can be invoked in this way.

I am also very aware of the issues around sensitive data such as cookies in `UserDefaults`, this is not a production app and long before release will have this functionality removed and replaced with a proper, secure solution. This is sadly just where we are with the product at this point in time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access `WKWebsiteDataStore` first, this will give you access to the cookie store.

```
func storeCookies() {

    let __cookies = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
    __cookies.httpCookieStore.getAllCookies { cookies in
        print(cookies)
    }
}
```